# n rows to n/2 columns : Sqlserver

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am having the table like this

```
insert into attn (StaffNo, ADate, ATime) values ('12345',   '12-02-2013',   09.10)
insert into attn (StaffNo, ADate, ATime) values ('12345',   '12-02-2013',   10.03)
insert into attn (StaffNo, ADate, ATime) values ('12345',    '12-02-2013',   10.40)
insert into attn (StaffNo, ADate, ATime) values ('12345',   '12-02-2013',   17.30)
```

I want in this format

OutPut:

```
     StaffNo        ADate       InTime     OutTime
      12333,      12-02-2013     09.10      10.03
      12333,      12-02-2013     10.40      17.30
```

Comment: Looks like you're using string/text/varchar columns for temporal data. That's a bad idea.

Comment: Does it means formatting output..?

Answer (score 1):

Something like this will work for your sample rows:

```
with attnJoin as
(
  select attn.StaffNo
  , attn.ADate
  , InTime = attn.ATime
  , OutTime = prev.ATime
  , eventNumber = row_number() over (partition by attn.StaffNo, attn.ADate order by attn.ATime)
  from attn
  outer apply
  (
    select top 1 ATime
    from attn prev
    where attn.StaffNo = prev.StaffNo
    and attn.ADate = prev.ADate
    and attn.Atime < prev.ATime
    order by ATime
  ) prev
)
select StaffNo
  , ADate
  , InTime
  , OutTime
from attnJoin
where eventNumber % 2 = 1
```

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/b20d2/12).

However this might be flaky in certain circumstances, e.g. missing data, multiple days, etc. Only you can find out for sure when looking at your live data.

Also, as has been noted, there might be more fundamental issues with the design, such as storing time separately from the date when there's no need. It would also be easier if you had a flag indicating which row was in/out.